# Get LAST in MySQL GROUP By query

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have a table of flights and struggling to identify the Last City each Flight# as landed at.

The incorrect query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `flight_nmbr`, COUNT(record_id) AS Flights,
MIN(`depart_date_time`) AS `first_flight`,
MAX(`depart_date_time`) AS `last_flight`,
MAX(`location`) AS `current_location`
FROM history 
GROUP BY `flight_nmbr`
HAVING records > 1
ORDER BY MAX(`depart_date_time`) DESC;
```

This statement will indicated the last flight (aircraft is currently located) is Winston-Salem, or Zanesville (which is the MAX City name).

I need the LAST location (the location from the MAX(depart_date_time)), the last / most recent flight, which is Atlanta and Houston.

Microsoft Access has a Last Function to Query, but we are migrating away from Access, using MySQL and PHP.

Can someone help tweak this query?

Many thanks!

Comment: So which is the column in question?City?

Comment: MAX will not work (as you want it to work) on "text" values, you need to build a specific query for this... (get location where flight id is the one with max depart_date_time)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Substring with GROUP_CONCAT trick

```
SELECT DISTINCT flight_nmbr,
 COUNT(record_id) AS Flights,
MIN(depart_date_time) AS first_flight,
MAX(depart_date_time) AS last_flight,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(location ORDER BY depart_date_time DESC),',',1) AS current_location
FROM history 
GROUP BY flight_nmbr
HAVING records > 1
ORDER BY MAX(depart_date_time) DESC;
```

Comment: Solved! I am not familiar with SUBSTRING_INDEX -or- GROUP_CONCAT, but will study up on these features.  Thank you Mihai